# get angularJS controller in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have controller defined as this:

```
var servicesInstance = angular.module('myApp');
servicesInstance.controller('ServicesViewController', function() {
    console.log("ServicesViewControllerconstructor."); 

    this.initialize = function() {
        console.log("ServicesViewController initialize."); 
    };

});
```

And I would like to get an instance of it dynamically in code like this:

```
var instance = $injector.get('ServicesViewController');
```

*Note:  please ignore the hardcoded strings.*  For this post, I hardcoded the strings.  however, in reality, the controller name will come from configuration data (eg: json object).

The instance variable is always null.  $injector.has('ServicesViewController') always returns false.

Why would this be the case?   Is this the correct way to get a controller instance?

Thank you
Matt

**EDIT**:
Throwing in more info I kept out because I was trying to keep the question simple.  I am using requireJS to load the javascript code which creates the controller.  EG:

```
define([], function(ServicesViewControllerProvider) {
    'use strict';

    var servicesInstance = angular.module('myApp');
    servicesInstance.controller('ServicesViewController', function() {
        console.log("ServicesViewController Constructor"); 

        this.initialize = function() {
            console.log("ServicesViewController initialize."); 
        };

    }); 

    var servicesViewController = new Object();
    servicesViewController.$inject=['$scope'];
    servicesViewController.view = "/test/ServicesView.html";
    servicesViewController.requiresUI = true;    
    servicesViewController.controllerName = "ServicesViewController";    

    return servicesViewController;    
});
```

Thanks
Matt

Comment: Actually that is not a controller its a service

Comment: see change in code.  sorry.  I am trying to get a controller not a service.  But should it matter when calling $injector.get?

Comment: var instance = $controller(''ServicesViewController", {});

Comment: If you don't need to have the controller registered first it might be easier to actually do this dynamically. 

angular.module("myApp").controller( var, function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way i know to get an instance of a controller

```
var instance = $controller('ServicesViewController');
```

parsing scope it is usually

```
//var instance = $controller('ServicesViewController',{$scope: $scope});
//call in service
servicesInstance.service('myService',function ($controller, $rootScope) {
   var scope = $rootScope.$new(true);
    //here you have  ServicesViewController scope
   var instance = $controller('ServicesViewController',{scope: $scope});

});
```

Comment: when I tried that earlier, I was getting an error on $scope.  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$scope' of undefined.  I tried defining the controller both with and without $scope injected.

Comment: Where you calling it in another controller or a service ?

Comment: Henry, can you point me to an example of how to use $modal to set scope?  thank you.

Comment: Have you tried that new edit to set controller scope?

Comment: Thank you for the example, Henry.  When I follow that, I get an unknown provider error:  Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $modalProvider <- $modal

Im not familar with $modal.  when I google, I get details about modal dialog services which doesn't sound like what we are discussion....

thnx

Comment: try to do it as in my last edit without all that.It should set your scope well. Seems i was making things more complicated

Comment: That answered my questions and solved one problem :)  Now on to the next.  Thank you.

Comment: what is the next one? When an answer helps you upvote it so that it helps amnother person in the same problem